# How to use Asynchronous Product Import in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, api

How to use Asynchronous Product Import in Magento 2 ?

I want to import product's using asynchronous API to import the products.

Is there any idea how to use them to import the data using asynchronous.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, what does it mean "Asynchronous Product Import" ?

Comment: Thanks for your response i have read https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/async-admin-rest-api.html#operation/quoteCartManagementV1CreateEmptyCartForCustomerPost article will it provide product import process using async process @HamendraSunthwal

Comment: i think this is what your talikng about POST /async/V1/products

Comment: Thanks for the response Yess @Pramod i think have you got it right have you any post or article how to use this and how many products are import in ( one minute or one hour )

Comment: only this all github post related to this has been removed i think https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-bulk-api-asynchronous-import.html